# Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object XAMPP to SQL SERVER 2012

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, xampp, sqlsrv

may I ask for some guide regarding this matter, I was trying out some test codes and guides on PHP to SQL SERVER, `mysqli` seems to work properly with phpmyadmin the following code, however, with `sqlsrv_connect` it doesn't seem to work, I understand that there's a different structure when it comes to MSSQL, may I ask for a link or any source I could find for connecting (or calling a query from PHP to SQL SERVER 2012)?

I did checked on all the questions asked here, unfortunately most of the questions are mysqli based, I haven't seen (or may have skipped) one that is SQL SERVER 2012 related.

I tried this guide `$query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);`, but no luck.

This is the code for login.php

```
    session_start();
    include 'includes/conn.php';

    if(isset($_POST['login'])){
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM usermasterfile WHERE username = '$username'";
        $query = $conn->query($sql);

        if($query->num_rows < 1){
            $_SESSION['error'] = 'Cannot find account with the username';
        }
        else{
            $row = $query->fetch_assoc();
            if(password_verify($password, $row['password'])){
                $_SESSION['admin'] = $row['id'];
            }
            else{
                $_SESSION['error'] = 'Incorrect password';
            }
        }

    }
    else{
        $_SESSION['error'] = 'Input admin credentials first';
    }

    header('location: index.php');

?>
```

And, this is the code for conn.php

```
$serverName = "XXXXXX\SQLSERVER";
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"XXXXXX", "UID"=>"XXXXXX", "PWD"=>"xxxxxx");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);

if( $conn ) {
     echo "Connection established.<br />";
}else{
     echo "Connection could not be established.<br />";
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
?>
```

This code works file (for phpmyadmin)

```
    $conn = new mysqli('xxxx', 'xxxx', '', 'xxxx');

    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }

?>
```

Connection is established, but the error is still the same.

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\path\tofile\login.php on line 9
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Functions `sqlsrv_*` are part of [PHP Driver for SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/microsoft-php-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017) and they are not object oriented. This is the reason for your error.

Your `conn.php` seems correct, so just use appropriate `sqlsrv_*` functions in `login.php`:

```
<?
    session_start();
    include 'includes/conn.php';

    if (isset($_POST['login'])) {
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM usermasterfile WHERE username = '$username'";
        $query = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql, array(), array("Scrollable" => SQLSRV_CURSOR_KEYSET));
        if ($query === false ) {
            echo "Error (sqlsrv_query): ".print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true);
            exit;
        }

        if (sqlsrv_num_rows($query) < 1) {
            $_SESSION['error'] = 'Cannot find account with the username';
        } else {
            $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($query, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC);
            if (password_verify($password, $row['password'])) {
                $_SESSION['admin'] = $row['id'];
            }
            else{
                $_SESSION['error'] = 'Incorrect password';
            }
        }
    }
    else{
        $_SESSION['error'] = 'Input admin credentials first';
    }

    header('location: index.php');
?>
```

Comment: @pjustindaryll Glad to help. I've added `sqlsrv` taq to your question.